# Upgrading to Magento 2

Tags: magento2, migration, magento2-migration-tool

I recently started a Magento 1.9.2.1 website that now has around 250 products. Whilst developing this, Magento 2 came out and I'm very keen to migrate my products and categories over to it. I've tried using the official [Magento 2 data migration tool](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-migrate.html) but it just doesn't work, it's awful to use and I get loads of errors every time I try to use it.

Is there an easier way I can migrate these products and categories over? I'm not bothered about migrating any other data across.

Comment: show the error snapshot you have faced.

Answer (score 1):

for data migration
place migration tool in root

careate folder if not exist
protected/runtime

```
give folder 777 permission
sudo chmod -R 777 migratedir
```

install sqllite

```
sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite
apt-cache search php | grep sqlite
```

migration is based on sqllite so you have to install.

than use the migration tool as bellow link.

https://github.com/ubertheme/magento2_data_migration/releases

i am not found other way to migrate because database and structure of magento 2 completely changed.

**I hope this will help you.**

Comment: are you wizard?? first we need to see his errors log

Comment: I am not wizard but I have many errors first time I migrate so the proper steps can remove errors OK buddy.